# How to Loop Through Rows of Data Values, That Are Pipe Delimited, and Check If Any of the Values Match the Previous Row

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

I have a data set that is only 1 column and is pipe delimited

```
7033 | 6010 | 873

6040 | 888

6017 | 6040 | 567
```

I am looking for the most efficient way (preferably VBA) to loop through all the rows in the column, and determine if any of the data in row N is equal to row N-1. I would like to be able to insert a value in the adjacent column that flags when this does occur with a "Y" or a "N".

In the example above, Row 2 does not match Row 1 but Row 3 matches Row 2 because of the value "6040"

Any advise or suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Any recommendation

Comment: Exactly which part is giving you problems?  You loop over the cells and use Split() to separate the values, then Match() to compare each value to the values in the cell above.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your data are in column A of Sheet1. This code can be optimized more, but right now it should be fast enough to handle hundreds of lines in seconds

```
Sub Main()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim str As String
    Dim arr As Variant
    Dim arr2 As Variant 'array of the result
    Dim arrTemp As Variant
    Dim rng As Range

    'put everything into an array
    Set rng = Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Columns(1)
    arr = rng.Value
    arr2 = arr
    arr2(1, 1) = "" 'delete the first row since there won't be any value above it to compare

    'loop thru the array rows and split the values of each element and compare it with the element above it
    For i = 2 To UBound(arr, 1)
        arrTemp = Split(arr(i, 1), " | ")

        arr2(i, 1) = "No" 'assume there is no match at first
        For j = 0 To UBound(arrTemp)
            If InStr(arr(i - 1, 1), arrTemp(j)) > 0 Then
                arr2(i, 1) = "Yes"
                Exit For 'there was a match get out
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

    'paste the results
    rng.Offset(0, 1).Value = arr2

End Sub
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that data is in A Column, Following code will give you the expected output.

```
Private Sub Test()
Dim i As Integer
For i = 4 To 2 Step -1
    j = i - 1
    PrevTempStr = Cells(j, "A")
    CurTempStr = Cells(i, "A")
    PreVal = Split(PrevTempStr, "|") 'Converts into array
    CurVal = Split(CurTempStr, "|")
    If MatchArray(CurVal, PreVal) Then 'Function to check if any of the element of current array matches with previous array
        Cells(i, "B") = "Y" 'Update Value Y in B column if matches
    Else
        Cells(i, "B") = "N"
    End If
Next
End Sub


Private Function MatchArray(Arg1 As Variant, Arg2 As Variant) As Boolean

    For i = LBound(Arg1) To UBound(Arg1)
        For j = LBound(Arg2) To UBound(Arg2)
            If Trim(Arg1(i)) = Trim(Arg2(j)) Then
                MatchArray= True
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    MatchArray= False
End Function
```